# Grabbing two words/phrases at a time

Tags: c++

I'm reading a text file with a bunch of words and i'm trying to read two words at a time from the file and then store the string in a map. If the phrase already exists its count just goes up. After that i want to print out all the words and how much times it occurred. Am i doing this right or is there a better way. I haven't read 2 words at a time so i'm not too familiar with that. When i ran the test code I wasn't getting the right phrases.

```
ifstream f;
f.open(argv[i]);

map <string, int> m;
string word, word2;
while(f >> word >> word2){  
    transform(word.begin(), word.end(), word.begin(), ::tolower); //transforms to lowercase
    transform(word2.begin(), word2.end(), word2.begin(), ::tolower);
    string p = word + " " + word2;
    m[p]++;   
}
for(map<string,int>::iterator i = m.begin(); i != m.end(); i++ ){
    cout << i->first << " " << i->second << endl;
}
f.close();
```

Comment: Do you need an `int` for the `map`? If not, you could just use a `std::set<std::string>`.

Comment: @George yea because the int counts how many times the phrase appears. Is the way i'm reading and adding the two words correct?

Comment: Your code is correct as far as I can tell. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: The `i` in the for loop and the `i` outside the loop shouldn't cause problems, but it's best to avoid having two variables with the same name like that.

Comment: I suspect that you're expected to count every adjacent pair. That is, "foo bar baz foo" has { "foo", "bar" }, { "bar", "baz" }, and { "baz", "foo" }. I suspect this because it's a slightly more interesting problem and could be the foundation of a Markov-chain text generator in a later exercise.

Comment: @molbdnilo you are right! I just looked over the test output and im supposed to be doing that. im guessing a map wouldn't be suitable for this? do you think i should use a list or a vector ?

Comment: @Darko A map is very good, you just need to restructure the way you build your pairs – don't read two words at at time, keep track of the last one you read instead.